# Markers Google Maps V3 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
var map

function detectBrowser() {
  var useragent = navigator.userAgent;
  var mapdiv = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

  if (useragent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 || useragent.indexOf('Android') != -1 ) {
    mapdiv.style.width = '100%';
    mapdiv.style.height = '100%';
  } else {
    mapdiv.style.width = '600px';
    mapdiv.style.height = '800px';
  }
}


function carregarMapa() {

    lat=document.getElementById("txtLat").value;
    lng=document.getElementById("txtLng").value;

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);



var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: myLatlng,
disableDefaultUI : false

  }

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  map.setOptions({styles: [
    {
     featureType: "poi",
     stylers: [
        { visibility: "off" }
     ]
    }
 ]});

}


function criaPonto(){

plat=document.getElementById("txtLat").value;
plng=document.getElementById("txtLng").value;

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(plat,plng);



var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Título Restaurante Y'});

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Olá, criei esse código no javascript tentando criar um mapa do google onde eu posso carregar markers, até o momento, só consegui criar markers se eu ficar resetando o mapa, e a ideia era criar esses markers em tempo de execução.
Por exemplo:
Criaria um marker se este estivesse a X de distância do ponto que meu sensor localizou, caso contrário, esse marker não é exibido.

**O Problema foi resolvido!**
Agradeço a ajuda do usuário : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/10196/migmar
Que foi bem presente e conseguiu me explicar os meus erros.

**Obrigado!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função initialize chamada na última linha do seu código não existe. Deve substituir o nome da função `carregarMapa()` por `initialize()`. A função `criaPonto()` nunca é chamada?
Tem de criar um método na função initialize que detecte a proximidade de novos pontos e aí chamar a função `criaPonto()`.

Tem de criar uma variável tipo array com nome markers, e depois adiciona cada marcador nessa variável, através da função `criaPonto()` com `markers.push(marker2)`.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta...
Então, a função carregarMapa() e criaPonto() são chamadas por botões no meu form html, segue o código:

    <body onload ="carregarMapa()">
    <input id="criaPonto" type="button" value="Cria Ponto" onclick="criaPonto()"/>

Comment: Ok, compreendi. Vamos por partes, a função carregarMapa() pode ser executada dessa forma. Mas a última linha de código "google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);" existe para isso mesmo. Repara, primeiro parâmetro é "window" + segundo parâmetro "load". Isto é igual a "body onload". O terceiro parâmetro é o nome da função que deverá ser chamada quando a página acaba de carregar. Por norma essa função é chamada de initialize, voce optou por carregarMapa. Retire o onload do elemento <body> e substitua initialize por carregarMapa.
Agora, como o valor de txtLat é actualizado?

Comment: Ok, alterei a linha e deletei o onload do body. Obrigado pela dica!
Entendi o porque ela se chama initialize graças a sua explicação! O valor de txtLat e txtLng são atualizados por um campo : <input id="txtLat"> por esse motivo dou um document.getElementById no código. Eu tinha tentado deixado o map como variável global, mas não conseguia carregar ele nas funções. vou tentar novamente depois

Comment: Tenho alguns artigos para iniciante em Google Maps API publicados em http://www.marnoto.com. Talvez possam ajudar a compreender a estrutura da criação dos mapas e marcadores.

Comment: Eu já acessei esse site, mas não consegui encontrar isso que perguntei aqui no stackflow.

Comment: Eu ainda não compreendi bem aquilo que pretendes fazer. Podes indicar o link para o teu site para que eu possa dar uma olhada no código?

Comment: Não está online, é um projeto que está local, mas passo o link do projeto para que possa testar localmente.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5kTRRclWirSamNKc183V0FGNHM/edit?usp=sharing

Oque quero é incluir marcadores sem precisar recarregar o mapa, no momento consigo incluir apenas um marcador e para isso preciso recarregar o mapa (mesmo usando-o como variável global)

Na verdade vou passar isso para um APP mobile, e ainda estou na fase de aprendizado e testes, mas futuramente precisarei de acesso ao GPS do usuário também...

Comment: Esse ficheiro está restrito, tem de dar permissão de acesso.